# Imprimir un array usando el Arrays.fill

Tags: java, array

Sé usar los bucles for para imprimir el array, pero existe alguna forma de imprimir el tablero de Tres en raya usando el Arrays.fill y que salga así:

> ```
> x x x
>
> x x x
>
> x x x
> ```

A mi solo me sale de esta forma: `[[x, x, x], [x, x, x], [x, x, x]]`

```
String [][]ar = new String[3][3];

for (String[] row : ar)
    Arrays.fill(row, "x");

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ar));
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ambos son lo mismo, un array que contiene 3 arrays de 3 `X`. Lo único que estás cambiando es *cómo lo imprimes*, pero el array, es el mismo. Si quieres imprimirlo en ese formato, tendrás que imprimirlo tú con un bucle, no te vale usar `Arrays.deepToString()`! Haz tu propio método que reciba un array y lo imprima como tú quieres, y no tendrás más que llamarlo en vez de `Arrays.deepToString(ar));`

Comment: Hola, @An_P, podrias marcar como aceptada la respuesta q mas te ayudo, gracias

Answer (score 3):

La manera más fácil de imprimir un array como tú quieres, es imprimirlo tú mismo!
Especialmente si vas a tener que imprimirlo varias veces, es mucho más rápido tener una función que lo imprima exactamente como quieres.

En este caso es muy sencillo usando loops for anidados, una técnica muy común a la hora de recorrer arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][]ar = new String[3][3];

    for (String[] row : ar)
        Arrays.fill(row, "x");

    printBoard(ar);
}

private static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
    // Ya que usas un foreach en el main lo usaré aquí también
    for(String[] row : board) {
        for (String letter : row)
            System.out.print(letter + " ");
        // Tras imprimir cada la línea, imprimo dos saltos de línea
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Tienes comentarios en el código, pero como ves es realmente sencillo.

---

El resultado es exactamente el esperado:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println("    " + Arrays.deepToString(ar).replace(",", "  ")
                                                   .replace("[", "")  
                                                   .replace("]", "\n"));
```

Aquí lo que se hace es que después de invocar al **método deepToString()**, como este devuelve una cadena de texto pues remplazamos los caracteres que nos interesan por otros.

Reemplazamos la coma (,) por 3 espacios.

Reemplazamos el corchete abierto ([) por un carácter vacío.

Reemplazamos el corchete cerrado (]) por un salto de línea.

También puedes usar esta forma:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ar).replace("],", "\n").
                                           replace("[[", "    ").
                                           replace(",", "   ").
                                           replace("[", "   ").
                                           replace("]", ""));
```

Ambas formas hacen lo mismo y no tienes que crear una nueva función.

Comment: Me temo que tu salida no pinta lo que piensas que pinta, fíjate que has reemplazado las comas por tres espacios... y no solo hay comas entre las X, si no también entre los diferentes array dentro del array principal, con lo cual todas las líneas excepto la primera saldrán con tres espacios a la izquierda, ergo, saldrán mal indentadas.

Comment: @Benito-B, ya lo arregle, era tan facil como añadir 4 espacios al inicio de la cadena